# Getting Internal server error in cpanel after uploading drupal7 project

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have run into a serious issue.I had my `drupal7` project working on the `localhost`.I tried uploading my project to `cpanels public_html` folder.But after i have finished uploading my complete project I get an `500 Internal server error`.I am sure i haven't edited edited anything `code-wise`.After i got this error i goggled it a lot and found that it may be caused due to `SymLinks` the `.htaccess` file.I tried editing it a lil bit.But it did not solve my problem.Could someone please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of the cases such error messages is caused due to the `.htaccess` file.Have you edited your `.htaccess` file while you were working on your `localhost`.If so, that change might be the culprit that prevents your precious site from being loaded.If you have no idea on what you have edited `replace` that file with the `default drupal's .htaccess`  file.

If you still find it not working try checking the `Error Log` from the `Logs section` in `cPanels`.
It might show what your problem is with your site.

Try checking the `file permissions`.Check if your folders and files are given not more or less that their `deserved permission`.Also try checking if the permission of `index.php` file in your project.If it is set to `777` permission,try giving it something like a `644` or `744` permission.Hope that might help u mate.. :)